# Отображение фото в слайд шоу

Tags: javascript, html, слайд-шоу

Вот есть код,для слайд шоу на JS,но изображение выводиться только после действия с элементами , как сделать что бы к примеру 1 фото выводилось сразу

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```html
    <div class="slideshow-container">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <div class="mySlides fade">
        <button class="button1">
            Детальніше
        </button>
        <div class="info">
            <h1>Insignia GSI</h1>
            <h3>Вже доступні для замовлення в Україні</h3>
        </div>
        <img src="C:\Users\maxim\Desktop\Магазин автосалону\src\img/1.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <button class="button1">
                Детальніше
            </button>
            <div class="info">
                <h1>Astra Electric</h1>
                <h3>Вже доступні для замовлення в Україні</h3>
            </div>
            <img src="C:\Users\maxim\Desktop\Магазин автосалону\src\img/2.jpg" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides fade">
            <button class="button1">
                Детальніше
            </button>
            <div class="info">
                <h1>Vivaro</h1>
                <h3>Вже доступні для замовлення в Україні</h3>
            </div>          
            <img src="C:\Users\maxim\Desktop\Магазин автосалону\src\img/3.jpeg" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>


    <div style="text-align:center">
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
        <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли что первое фото не выводится сразу?

Comment: ну лично у меня в браузере Google Chrome не выводит после загрузки сайта, только при нажатии на 3 точки выводит изображение

Comment: Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с тем [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), в предоставленном вами коде всё работает прекрасно и никаких точек нет.